# How to re-run a java program with connection to a database for the second time without terminating the JVM?

Tags: java, database, database-connection, connection-pooling

Following is my connection pool code

```
public class ConnectionPoolManager {

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log;
    private String databaseUrl;
    String userName = null;
    String password = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Vector connectionPool = new Vector();

    public ConnectionPoolManager() {

        databaseUrl();
        initialize();


    }

    public void databaseUrl() {

        try {
            URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("database.properties");

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(url.getPath()));
            // get the property value
            databaseUrl = prop.getProperty("database");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("Date & Time: " + new Date() + ", Class Name : ConnectionPoolManager, Method Name : databaseUrl"
                    + "\n" + "Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Date & Time: " + new Date() + ", Class Name : ConnectionPoolManager, Method Name : databaseUrl"
                    + "\n" + "Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        userName = prop.getProperty("username");
        password = prop.getProperty("password");

    }


    public ConnectionPoolManager(String databaseUrl, String userName, String password) {
        this.databaseUrl = databaseUrl;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // Here we can initialize all the information that we need
        initializeConnectionPool();
    }

    private void initializeConnectionPool() {
        while (!checkIfConnectionPoolIsFull()) {
            System.out.println("Connection Pool is NOT full. Proceeding with adding new connections");
            // Adding new connection instance until the pool is full
            connectionPool.addElement(createNewConnectionForPool());
        }
        System.out.println("Connection Pool is full");
    }

    private synchronized boolean checkIfConnectionPoolIsFull() {
        final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 5;

        // Check if the pool size
        if (connectionPool.size() < 5) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Creating a connection
    private Connection createNewConnectionForPool() {
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            // connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, userName,
            // password);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + sqle);
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + cnfe);
            return null;
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public synchronized Connection getConnectionFromPool() {

        Connection connection = null;

        // Check if there is a connection available. There are times when all
        // the connections in the pool may be used up
        if (connectionPool.size() > 0) {
            connection = (Connection) connectionPool.firstElement();
            connectionPool.removeElementAt(0);
        }
        // Giving away the connection from the connection pool
        return connection;
    }

    /**
     * The method adds the connection from the client back to the connection
     * pool
     * 
     * @return void
     * @param connection
     */
    public synchronized void returnConnectionToPool(Connection connection) {
        // Adding the connection from the client back to the connection pool
        connectionPool.addElement(connection);
    }

}
```

In my implementation class I have used finally block to close connection.
I do not want to invoke `System.exit(0)` from my code.
My current code runs for the first time and inserts the data into database, but without terminating the JVM.

When I try running next time it gives Connection closed exception, but I want it to be inserting into database.
How will I be able to solve this?

Comment: Well, if you close a connection you can't use it anymore. But what's the problem with either keeping it open or creating a new one?

Comment: I don't want it to be open all time, but what modification should I do in connection code to establish a connection again ?

Comment: Is there a way to create two different connections and when I run for the second time the first one will be killed and so on. Is this possible to implement?

Comment: Well, you know how to create one connection (`connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);`) so what's the problem with creating another one like this? Note that connection pools normally keep the connections open in order to reduce the overhead. So when a user hands back the connection it might not get closed at all (unless the pool figures there are allready too many connections and decides to remove some).

Comment: what will i have to do if the code is being hit several times?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code is being hit"? If you mean that there are multiple requests you basically hand out connections and create new ones until you decides you have too many. In that case you'd then probably have to let requests wait until connections are getting handed back. Naturally any request should aquire a connection only when it really needs it and hand it back as soon as possible. That being said, if you want to create your own connection pool you probably should read up on the topic some more.